# How to parse XML Name and Attribute (Complex) using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Hi there I am trying to parse some financial information out of an XML file using python into a JSON format.

currently using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse(filename)  
root = tree.getroot()

# all items
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in root:
    all_descendants = [e.tag.split('}', 1)[1] for e in elem.iter()]
    print(all_descendants)
```

as an example of the XML:

```
  <pt:ShareholderFunds decimals="0" unitRef="GBP" contextRef="e2020-01-31">4</pt:ShareholderFunds>
  <pt:ShareholderFunds decimals="0" unitRef="GBP" contextRef="e2019-01-31">4</pt:ShareholderFunds>
  <pt:ApprovalDetails>
        <pt:NameApprovingDirector contextRef="y2020-01-31">Mr FAKE FAKE</pt:NameApprovingDirector>
      </pt:ApprovalDetails>
<pt:DetailsOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    <pt:TypeOrdinaryShare contextRef="y2020-01-31">Ordinary</pt:TypeOrdinaryShare>
    <pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare decimals="0" contextRef="y2020-01-31" unitRef="GBP">1</pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare>
    <pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted decimals="0" contextRef="e2020-01-31" unitRef="GBP">4</pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    <pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted decimals="0" contextRef="e2019-01-31" unitRef="GBP">4</pt:ValueOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    <pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted decimals="0" contextRef="e2020-01-31" unitRef="shares">4</pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted>
    <pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted decimals="0" contextRef="e2019-01-31" unitRef="shares">4</pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAllotted>
  </pt:DetailsOrdinarySharesAllotted>
  <pt:EquityAuthorisedDetails>
    <pt:TypeOrdinaryShare contextRef="y2020-01-31">Ordinary</pt:TypeOrdinaryShare>
    <pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAuthorised decimals="0" unitRef="shares" contextRef="e2020-01-31">0</pt:NumberOrdinarySharesAuthorised>
    <pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare decimals="0" contextRef="y2020-01-31" unitRef="GBP">1</pt:ParValueOrdinaryShare>
  </pt:EquityAuthorisedDetails>
```

And it works great getting the Names:
['ShareholderFunds']
['ApprovalDetails', 'NameApprovingDirector']

however I need it to get the values with this as well. Does anyone know how to do this?

Ideally the output would look like this:

```
{
        {
            "name": "ShareholderFunds",
            "value": 4,
            "unitRef": "GBP",
            "contextRef": "e2020-01-31",
        },

    {
       "name": "ApprovalDetails"
        {
            "name": "NameApprovingDirector",
            "value": "Mr FAKE FAKE"
            "contextRef": "y2020-01-31",
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "DetailsORdinarySharesAlloted"
        {
            "name":"TypeOrdinaryShare",
            "contextRef":"y2020-01-31",
            "value":"Ordinary"
        },
        {
            "name":"ParValueOrdinaryShare",
            "contextRef": "e2020-01-31",
            "unitRef":"GBP",
            "value":"4"  
        }
    } etc...
}
```

I am sure someone can point me in the right direction (I've manually typed the JSON so if there are errors they're just me not typing correctly)

Thank you in advance

Comment: _however I need it to get the values with this as well._ Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I can get the "Name" of the tags but not the value/ attributes it has inside. E.g. I can pull out ShareholderFunds which is the tags name. E.g.

  <pt:ShareholderFunds decimals="0" unitRef="GBP" contextRef="e2020-01-31">4</pt:ShareholderFunds> 

I want to get the rest of the information out of the Tag.

Comment: Isn’t that covered in the docs?

Comment: I can see your profile description doesn't lie. The answer was in the docs. I was just being lazy. Thanks for pointing me in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```